# SQL Bucket Time Stamp into incrementsof 2 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to write a sql to bucket the time into an increment of 2 hours.
For example 0-2, 2-4, 6-8, ………18-20, 20-22, 22-24

```
Time             I want it to be
6/8/2015 20:49       20-22
6/5/2015 12:47       12-14
6/9/2015 16:46       16-18
```

Thanks,

Comment: What queries have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a case expression and some simple arithmetic to group the time values into buckets:

```
select
    time, 
    case 
       when datepart(hour, time) % 2 = 0 then  -- n % 2 = 0 determines if hour is even
          cast(datepart(hour, time) as varchar(2))
          + '-'
          + cast(datepart(hour, time) + 2 as varchar(2))
       else  -- hour is odd
          cast(datepart(hour, time) - 1 as varchar(2))
          + '-'
          + cast(datepart(hour, time) + 1 as varchar(2))
    end as bucket
from t
```

Note that I made the assumption that the odd hours should be bucketed into the even numbered buckets, and that there should not be any odd buckets (like 1-3, 3-5 etc).

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1eec6/2)

Sample output:

```
|                   time | bucket |
|------------------------|--------|
| June, 08 2015 00:49:00 |    0-2 |
| June, 08 2015 23:49:00 |  22-24 |
| June, 08 2015 20:49:00 |  20-22 |
| June, 05 2015 12:47:00 |  12-14 |
| June, 05 2015 13:47:00 |  12-14 |
| June, 09 2015 16:46:00 |  16-18 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
SELECT (RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) AS CHAR))+'-'+ CAST((DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())+2) AS CHAR))

Answer (score 0):

Simple integer division can drop everything in the right buckets for you.  For example, 1/2 = 0, 2/2 = 1, 3/2 = 1, etc.  After that it is just a matter of formatting the output:

```
select
    time, 
    cast((datepart(hour, time)/2)*2 as varchar(2))+'-'+ cast((datepart(hour, time)/2)*2+2 as varchar(2)) as bucket
from t
```

Note that the division of two integers defaults to integer division, which is why this works.